# inserting figures and pictures in table

Tags: tables

How can I create the following figure ((see attached picture))?
[image: micrograph image for each spectrum]

Comment: There are several ways, but the easiest would be to use a tabular with multirow for the left image.  Or you could put all the images on the right into a minipage or \parbox, perhaps using \fbox to draw the lines.  Or you could draw the whole thing using TikZ and put each image into a node.

Comment: sorry mate could you please sent these comments. actually I coudn't get it.

Comment: It would be easier if you would provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE), preferably using images from the MWE package.  But i will try to show examples of each approach RSN.

Comment: Are the black borderlines needed?  Do want gaps between the actual images or flush?

Comment: Actually I want to keep constant gap or flush between the images to be related to the next line in plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tabular solution involves a few fudge factors to get the images vertically centered in their respective fields.  The fbox/parbox solution requires a fudge factor to overlap the fbox borders.

```
\documentclass[legalpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newcommand{\adj}[1]{\raisebox{-2pt}[\height][\depth]{#1}}
\newlength{\tempwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}[14pt]{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}}
 & \adj{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}}\\
\cline{2-2}
 & \adj{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}}\\
\cline{2-2}
 & \adj{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}\\
\cline{2-2}
 & \adj{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{using tabular}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\settowidth{\tempwidth}{\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}}}% compute width of small image
\fboxsep=0pt
\centering\fbox{
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}} 
\parbox[c]{\tempwidth}{\fboxsep=3pt
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}}\vspace{-1.2pt}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}}\vspace{-1.2pt}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}\vspace{-1.2pt}
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}}}}
\caption{using fbox and parbox}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[left] (main) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}};
\node[above right,draw] (B) at (main.east) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[above,draw] (A) at (B.north) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[below right,draw] (C) at (main.east) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}};
\node[below,draw] (D) at (C.south) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}};
\draw (A.north west) -| (main.west) |- (D.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{using tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: examples]

Comment: I wonder if the borders are actually needed or were just to clarify that there are 4 pics on the left. Maybe it's because the MWE-pics have borders themselves, but it looks strange. Nonetheless, nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just for exercises, a variant of third case in @John Kormylo answer:

```
\documentclass[legalpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,chains}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm,
  start chain = going below,
figure/.style = {inner sep=1mm, on chain}
                    ]
\node[figure] (A)   {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[figure] (B)   {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[figure] (C)   {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[figure] (D)   {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}};
\path   let \p1 = ([yshift=-1mm] A.north),
            \p2 = ([yshift=+1mm] D.south),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in
        node[figure,left=of B.south west] {\includegraphics[height=\n1] {example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{using tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]